# Cannot pass multiple arguments to contract's method in Web3

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, truffle, ganache

I'm using Web3 to interact with my ethereum contract. The problem is I cannot pass more than one argument when calling the method. If I pass two or more does not work even when in my contract the method defines that receive two or more args.

I already try to encapsulate all the arguments inside a object/array/etc,nothing works.

This works fine.

```
  adicionaFatura: function(valor,data,hashF){
    let self = this

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      self.instance.adicionaFatura(
        hashF,
        {from: window.web3.eth.accounts[0]}
      ).then(exists => {
        resolve(exists)
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
        console.log('erro: ' + err)
      })
    })
```

This does not work.

```
  adicionaFatura: function(valor,data,hashF){
    let self = this

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      self.instance.adicionaFatura(
        valor,
        data,
        hashF,
        {from: window.web3.eth.accounts[0]}
      ).then(exists => {
        resolve(exists)
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
        console.log('erro: ' + err)
      })
    })
```

Solidity code

```
    function adicionaFatura(uint valor, string memory emitData, bytes32 hash) public {
        require(isMember(msg.sender) == true,"Sender not authorized.");

        Fatura memory myStruct = Fatura({valorTotal:valor, data:emitData, estadoVenda:1});
        KeysFaturas.push(hash);
        transacoes[hash] = myStruct;
        emit nextStage(hash,1);
    }
```

Error:
[image: Error after confirm the transaction]

Comment: can you please also share your solidity code.

Comment: Already did it! :D

Comment: can you also share the error message ?

Comment: Unable to find value for the key. I am assuming that they value of the hash pushed earlier (transacoes[hash]) ?

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if you write the relevant variables too in the solidity code.